# Embassy made correction on my handwritten visa

Tags: visas, india, mali

I am visiting Mali from India next week. I had applied for the Visa via Mali embassy in Delhi. The embassy made a mistake in the hand written visa. Embassy allotted me a 3 month multiple entry visa, starting 13th June, (13-06-2017), but put expiry date as 12-06-2017, instead of 12-09-2017. I went back to the embassy, and they corrected the hand written visa by hand, probably using a blade, by removing the "06" and replacing it with "09". The correction is not obvious but clearly visible on close inspection.

Will I face any issues in India or Mali due to this?

[image: See pic for refence]

Answer (score 5):

Mali is one of the 20 poorest countries in a World with extremely low developed governmental infrastructures.

In such a cases officials rely on stamps as a proof of the legitimacy of a document, not a secured database.

Your visa clearly states **Length of stay: 3 months**, so do not worry and in case you'll be asked by a board guard, just tell them it was an embassy clerk, who made this correction.

Answer (score 5):

Nobody can tell you definitively if you will face problems however I would not fret over it. Some of the developing economies in Africa are more lax on visa protocol and the scenario you describe is not unheard of. I know because I am originally from there. The unedited 3 months length of stay written on there is in your favor.

If you're that concerned you can get a letter from the embassy. Worst case scenario immigration officer at the airport asks for some [payola](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/payola)